# Variable URL for json call in Angular service

Tags: angular

I use an Angular service to get JSON data from a URL. Code is below,

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {FilterJson} from "./filter-json";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private postsURL ="http://myapp/explore/json1";

  constructor(private http: Http ) {}
 getPosts(): Observable<FilterJson[]>{
    return this.http
     .get(this.postsURL)
     .map((response: Response)=> {
       return <FilterJson[]>response.json();
     })
     .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(error: Response) {
   return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }
}
```

Now I have created several json files as json2, json3 and json4. By a click event in a component markup, I need to change the json file in the URL.

For an example, I have three anchor tags in markup of the component. I need to get each json file by clicking on each anchor. How I can do this?

Comment: Make `postsURL` public and then on `(click)` event, change the URL from `component`, provided that you have injected the service in your component.

Comment: Add json file name as an argument to `getPosts()` and append the json file name to the url `http://myapp/explore/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass jsonfile names json1|json2|json3 as input param to the get posts method.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {FilterJson} from "./filter-json";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private postsURL ="http://myapp/explore/";

  constructor(private http: Http ) {}
 getPosts(accesstype): Observable<FilterJson[]>{
    const _postsURL = this.postsURL + accesstype;
    return this.http
     .get(_postsURL)
     .map((response: Response)=> {
       return <FilterJson[]>response.json();
     })
     .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(error: Response) {
   return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }
}
```

Comment: accesstype means an array of json file names?

Comment: no, its only string lets say 'json1'. Or you can maintain Array of JSON Files and pass only array index. It's up to you to choose